Jmeter with Android device Issue
I am working on jmeter for performance testing with mobile applications (Android and IOS).
But I am unable to connect the Android device into jmeter.




For Android you will additionally need to amend your applications network security settings like:

In the application tag of your app manifest add the next line:
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"


Create network_security_config.xml file under your application resources directory and put the following code there:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <debug-overrides>
        <trust-anchors>
            <!-- Trust user added CAs while debuggable only -->
            <certificates src="user" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </debug-overrides>
</network-security-config>


Build your application in debug mode

Replace the original .apk on the device with the newly built one


More information: Configure Android Devices for Proxy Recording

From Android 7 (Nougat) onwards CA certificate are not supported.
Refer this article: https://portswigger.net/burp/documentation/desktop/mobile/config-android-device
Ask your developer for pinning the CA certificate in the APK itself to allow proxy setting for interception.
Cheers!
